# Unity: Component not being serialized

Tags: unity, serialization

I have a script like this:

```
public class A: MonoBehaviour {
   public bool x = false;
}
```

... and a Custom Editor like this:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(A))]
public class A_E: Editor
{
   public override void OnInspectorGUI()
   {
      A a= target as A;
      if (a== null || a.gameObject == null) return;
      a.x = !EditorGUILayout.Toggle("x", !a.x);
   }
}
```

When I enter play mode, the property resets.

I tried fixing it by adding:

```
if(GUI.changed) EditorUtility.SetDirty(a);
```

However this only fixed it for play mode.
If I save and close the scene, it resets to the default.
Also, the scene is not set to dirty, if I make changes to the component through the custom editor.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice the [docs for SetDirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) point out that this method has been replaced:

> Prior to Unity 5.3, this was the primary method of marking objects as
>   dirty. From 5.3 onwards, with the introduction of Multi-Scene Editing,
>   this function should no-longer be used for modifying objects in
>   scenes. Instead, you should use Undo.RecordObject prior to making
>   changes to the object. This will mark the object's scene as dirty and
>   provide an undo entry in the editor.

Here's how your code would look with this pattern:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI() { 
    A a= target as A; 

    if (a== null || a.gameObject == null) 
         return; 

    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
    bool x = !EditorGUILayout.Toggle("x", !a.x); 
    if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()) {
        Undo.RecordObject(target, "Changed x");
        a.x = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah...thanks! I already changed my editor scripts to use `serializedObject.FindProperty("myProperty");`, `EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(myProperty, new GUIContent("My Property"));` and `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();`.

Comment: Feel free to add that as another answer, as it's also a completely valid way to handle serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that I ultimately went with:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(A))]
public class A_E: Editor
{
   private SerializedProperty x;

   public OnEnable(){
      x = serializedObject.FindProperty("x");
   }

   public override void OnInspectorGUI()
   {
      serializedObject.Update();
      x.boolValue = !EditorGUILayout.Toggle("x", !x.boolValue);
      serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```